# SharpSVN checkout creates local directory but it is not a working copy

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I'm using the standard constructor for the client which is in a Branch class:

```
this.svn = newSvnClient();
```

Another method in the Branch class does the remote copy:

```
this.svn.RemoteCopy(this.trunk, this.branch, copy)
```

Lastly, another method in the same class checks out:

```
this.svn.CheckOut(this.branch, this.localCopy)
```

The directory is created where I expect to be but it is NOT a working copy, just a plain old folder with all the files in. I have tried `svn.Authentication.Clear()` and `svn.Authentication.DefaultCredentials` with SslServerTrustHandlers just in case authentication was an issue. These didn't work. What could be the problem?

```
/*
 * Class representing a single branch 
 */
class Branch
{

    public SvnClient svn {get; set;}
    public Uri trunk {get; set;}
    public string localCopy {get; set;} //path to local working copy
    public Uri branch {get; set;} //repo location of new branch to be created
    public string branchName {get; set;}


    public Branch(string branchName, Uri trunk = null)
    {

        this.trunk = trunk ?? new Uri("repo trunk location"); 
        this.branchName = branchName;

        this.svn = new SvnClient();

        this.localCopy = String.Format("C:\\branches\\{0}", this.branchName.Trim());
        this.branch = new Uri(String.Format("repo branch location", this.branchName.Trim()));

    }

    //check if branch on repo already exists
    public static bool checkBranchExists(Uri branch, SvnClient client)
    {
        Collection<SvnInfoEventArgs> info;
        bool branchExists = client.GetInfo(branch, new SvnInfoArgs { ThrowOnError = false }, out info);
        return branchExists;

    }

    //check if local copy already exists
    public static bool checkLocalBranchExists(String localCopy)
    {
        bool localBranchExists = Directory.Exists(localCopy);
        return localBranchExists;

    }

    //CopyTo trunk to branches
    private void CopyTo()
    {
        SvnCopyArgs copy = new SvnCopyArgs();
        copy.LogMessage = "creating new branch";

        if (!checkBranchExists(this.branch, this.svn))
        {
            this.svn.RemoteCopy(this.trunk, this.branch, copy);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new SvnException(); //branch already exists on repo
        }

    }

    //checkout from branches on repo to local working copy
    public void Checkout()
    {


        try
        {
            if (!checkLocalBranchExists(this.localCopy))
            {
                CopyTo();
                this.svn.CheckOut(this.branch, this.localCopy); 
            }
            else
            {
                throw new IOException();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException is SvnException)
                MessageBox.Show("Branch already exists on repo", "CopyTo Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            else
            {
                if (ex.InnerException is IOException)
                    MessageBox.Show("Branch already exists locally", "Checkout Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }           

    }
}
```

UPDATE: I am using Subversion 1.7. I understand that after 1.6, a checkout doesn't create a working copy which means the directory has to upgraded to become a working working copy by using `svn upgrade`. Is this possible with SharpSVN?

Comment: Steps that you have described should be working just fine. Please show us your real code. Do you see any error? And how do you know that is not a working copy? .svn folder is not present?  Or icon overlay is not showing "green checked" icon?

Comment: Will update the code in a bit but yes, no green icon and commit fails.

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine on my machine:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://path-to-svn/svn/test/branch");
Uri branchUri = new Uri("https://path-to-svn/svn/test/branch-copy");
SvnTarget target = SvnTarget.FromUri(uri);
SvnUriTarget targetBranch = new SvnUriTarget(branchUri);

SvnClient client = new SvnClient();
client.Authentication.ForceCredentials("user", "pass");
SvnCopyArgs sca = new SvnCopyArgs();
sca.LogMessage = "here goes some log message";
client.RemoteCopy(target, branchUri, sca);
client.CheckOut(targetBranch, "folder-to-checkout");
```

It should be more-less the same as yours. Please test it and let us know the result.

Comment: I have added my class with methods that do this.

Comment: I have tried it that way and it still just produces an unversioned directory.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was the mismatch between the version of the repo's subversion, my local subversion and the SharpSVN version, in this case all three had to be version 1.7.18.